# How versatile are c++'s templates?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, branch

I want to write a highly optimized code in C++ and there is a templated structure which takes a type variable `T`. There is one function `wow()` in that structure that can be optimized to run twice faster if and only if the size of `T` is a power of 2. Can I use the better version of `wow()` without doing branching (use `if` or something) at the beginning of every call to `wow()`?

I understand (I hope I do) that C++ creates a copy (or better say instantiation) of my structure for every type `T` I use it with, so can I tell that "struct builder" which version of `wow()` to use depending on the size of `T`?

Comment: You can try to use `constexpr if`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if. You'll need to find a constexpr way to determine if sizeof(T) is a power of 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [*constexpr if*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) and [`std::has_single_bit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/has_single_bit):

```cpp
#include <bit>

template<class T>
struct foo {
    void wow() {
        if constexpr (std::has_single_bit(sizeof(T))) {
            // sizeof(T) is a power of two
        } else {
            // not a power of two
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I was not familiar with `std::has_single_bit`. Good to know - thanks.

Comment: @wohlstad You're welcome! I'm surprised it took so long to get these `<bit>` functions standardized :-)